NCQ support on paravirtualized disks
Do paravirtualized disks in VMware, VirtualBox, XEN or KVM support NCQ ?

Is this dependent on the underlaying physical disk (NCQ support passed through virtualization with the same queue depth as the physical disk) ?
Are the various hypervisor interfaces always advertising a uniform virtualized queue per virtual disk ?
Are all paravirtualized disks always rejecting queued IO ?
Does paravirtualized NCQ support depend on underlaying storage type, which might be a local virtual disk file, a passed through physical disk or disk partition or a remote NAS file or SAN volume ?

This is intended as a general question with the hope that there is a general answer which is independent of storage type, host OS and hypervisor. If there are different answers for different hypervisors, host OS or types of underlaying storage, please specify. I would then split this general question into a number of more specific questions, if needed.
